# configuring Laravel 5.2 on windows server 2008 r2, IIS 7.5

Tags: php, laravel, web-config, iis-7.5, laravel-5

I was trying to setup laravel 5.2 in IIS 7.5 using PHP 5.6, I am able to access index.php only if it's directly accessed such as `<h1>works</h1>` or `<?PHP phpInfo(); ?>` both these cases work fine but when I try to use following my index.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

it's giving me an error pointing to web.config

web.config 1st try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

web.config second try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                    <match url="^.*index.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                    <match url="^m(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="m/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

both config files didn't work.

giving me an HTTP Error 500 Internal Server Error

Please advice me

Comment: You should use the `web.config` that is included with the framework. No need to change that. Furthermore it won't be possible to provide a specific answer to this question without aditional details, such as: how did you configure IIS? Did you create a virtual directory? What is the URL you're using? What is the specific error it's throwing (see IIS errors and PHP errors)

Comment: sorted this out, the issue was because of file permissions from IIS